# What will be the time complexity of a function having thousands of constant time taking operations?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a doubt regarding the time complexity of the function having thousands of constant time taking operation, like simple addition 
y = x+z
will it be 
O(number of operations) 
or
O(1) as all the operations are taking constant time.

```
pyhton
def add(x, z) :
   x = x+y
   x = x+y
   .
   .
   .


....(almost thousand times)
   print(x)
add(5, 6)
```

Comment: it is still O(1). Consider the time it takes from you to write this code. For a computer, it takes millions and millions of times less too execute this code.

Comment: O(1) If the number of times is fixed.
O(n) if the number of times it performs the action is based on the z parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) about the `O` notation:

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity

So, as you can see, the fact that a function will perform thousands, or even millions of operations is not relevant to its 'big O' time complexity **as long as the number of operations performed is independant of the input size.**

In the example you present, it looks like the number of operations does not depend on the input size, so its time complexity is `O(1)`.

For instance, let's see these two small functions:

```
def runs_in_constant_time(n):
    for _ in range(100000000000000):   # may take a while
        print(n)
```

This function might keep running for billions of year, but it runs in `O(1)` nonetheless because its running time does not depend on `n`'s size or value.
On the other hand,

```
def runs_in_linear_time(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        print(n)
```

runs in linear time, meaning in `O(n)`, because if we double the value of `n`, the running time will be doubled as well.